# How to invoke ActiveRecord statement in a bundle subshell?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a rake task that invokes a bundle subshell and uses ActiveRecord 3.x/4.x (depending on what is passed in args):

```
task :some_task do |t, args|
    Bundler.with_clean_env do
      ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = File.expand_path(args[:gemfile] || (File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/test/config/gemfiles/Gemfile.rails-3.2.x'))
      ENV['DB'] = args[:db] || 'mysql2'


      system "bundle install"

      # ActiveRecord::Base.configurations = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/config/database.yml')).result)
  end
end
```

I want to be able to set ActiveRecord::Base.configurations to a particular configuration in database.yml as above.  I thought to try something like after the bundle install statement:

```
system 'bundle exec ruby -e ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.some_method_which_always returns_an_error"'
```

Usually I get either "uninitialized constant ActiveRecord (NameError)" or syntax error when I try "require %(active_record); && ActiveRecord::Tasks::Databas...",

1)  Is it possible to initialize ActiveRecord::Base.configurations in a particular bundle subshell independent of Rails?

2)  If yes to #1, how to do that?

The whole point is to be able to use different version of ActiveRecord via a clean "bundle install" called by the Ruby Kernel#system command